# How to extract years as an array from pandas df

Tags: python-3.x, pandas, list, dataframe, datetime

How can I extract years as an array from pandas df date-time object? When trying
`years = ([employees['Hiring Date'].dt.year])`, the "years" comes as a list.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- Use [`pandas.Series.to_numpy`](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.Series.to_numpy.html)

```py
from datetime import datetime
import pandas as pd

# data
data = {'Hiring Date': pd.bdate_range(datetime(1971, 1, 1), freq='2m', periods=40).tolist()}

# dataframe
employees = pd.DataFrame(data)

# extract years
years = employees['Hiring Date'].dt.year.to_numpy()

print(years)
[1971 1971 1971 1971 1971 1971 1972 1972 1972 1972 1972 1972 1973 1973
 1973 1973 1973 1973 1974 1974 1974 1974 1974 1974 1975 1975 1975 1975
 1975 1975 1976 1976 1976 1976 1976 1976 1977 1977 1977 1977]

print(type(years))
<class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(years.shape)
(40,)
```

Answer (score 0):

This could not work for you since I might have misread your post but I would try:

```
years = df['hiring date'].values
```

And then:

```
years = np.array(years)
```